# Java to introduced the temporary objects

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm

I am not able to see any major GC is getting triggered in my application server. This is because, I have assigned more memory which is 4GB. And maximum it is going upto 1GB. I just want to see a Full GC to be happened.

To triggered a Full GC , I need to full the heap memory which is not possible while my application is running. So, Planning to put some temporary object while starting the server and fill the Heap at lease 3.5GB.

Can anybody help me out to give me some approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ermmm .... use `new` to allocate a large array.  Or allocate a list and add lots of elements to it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @bradimus I just want a full GC to be happen in my application server with out changing any parameter ...

Comment: @StephenC Lets say I have created a large array of 1MB where thousands of object reside. How many array do I need to create in that case?

Comment: Heap is divided into sections (young and old generations). Objects are stored in those sections based on how long they survive (how long they remain reachable). A GC occurs when a section needs more room to store objects, removing dead objects. The reachable objects in the section being cleared move onto the next section, while dead objects are claimed. AFAIK, a full GC is only required if the old generation needs more room.

Comment: Why do you need a full GC?

Comment: @IgCiphEr - The calculation is difficult and it would require extensive research to figure out how the spaces would be dimensioned, etcetera.  It is better to figure it out by trial and error.

Comment: @StephenC Completely agree...

Comment: @VinceEmigh Completely agree and well known about the theory. My question is how we can able to put some temporary object and make Old gen full. So that We can see a Full GC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple code for temporary object creatation . Hope , it may help you.

```
for(int i=0;i<100000;++i){
map.put(UUID.randomUUID(),UUID.randomUUID());
}
```

declare the map as a global variable and on each request execute this loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger GC from the code by: `System.gc()`
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc()

Comment: Not guaranteed to do anything.  Not guaranteed to trigger a Full GC.

Comment: @StephenC I agree with you.

Comment: One more thing is , in my code base while running I cannot even think to put this code.

Comment: `System.gc()` and related JNI and management APIs are guaranteed to do something *on specific JVMs with specific settings*. It's just not guaranteed by the JRE APIs. So if you look further than just at the JRE APIs (which is applicable here since tag:jvm) then it's a valid thing to suggest if you are aware of the details.

Comment: @the8472 - Guaranteed means "specified in the official Oracle documentation".  What you are talking about is behavior that is known to work with specific versions / settings, but could stop working if you change settings or update to a new patch release.  (Particularly the point about whether `gc()` triggers a >>full<< GC.)  Since new patch releases are coming out every month or so, the is something that it is difficult for people to stay on top if. Your *"if you are aware of the details"* is not realistic for most Java programmers.

Comment: Most java programmers don't need to control the GC. If you do then yes you do have to be aware of the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform

```
jmap -histo:live {pid}
```

and this will trigger a full collection in any Java application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the required gist where the above scenarios has been replicated and tested using visualVM.

https://gist.github.com/cooligc/eb9ba490e14a10d939147bd9c914afdd

Comment: Please edit your question, rather than adding an answer

Comment: What do you want to me edit in the question @AlBlue ?

Answer (score -2):

When the GC is triggered it only cleans the objects that you do not have access to any more (their references point to null);
So make sure to assign null to objects' references after completing using them

```
SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
  /*
     use obj
  */
  obj = null;
```

That's how the GC knows that the object needs to be cleaned.

You can also take a look on soft reference and weak reference.

Comment: How many object do I need to create and reference them to null ? 
And one more thing, If I am referencing object to null, then this will be collected by Minor GC. If It is going to Tenured then , It can be cleaned using Major GC.

Comment: You usually don't have to assign to null. If the variable referencing the object is declared in a method, and no other variablea reference that object, the object will become unreachable as soon as the method ends.